# Can I remove element from a list being looped through

Tags: apex, list

In apex, how can I remove an element from a list being looped?

```
List<String> companyinfos=new List<String>();
companyinfos.add('a1');
companyinfos.add('a2');
companyinfos.add('a3');
companyinfos.add('b1');
companyinfos.add('b2');

integer index=0;
For(String s: companyinfos)
{
    if(s.contains('a')){
        companyinfos.remove(index);
        index--;
    }
index++;
}  


System.debug(companyinfos);
```

ERROR:
Cannot modify a collection while it is being iterated.

Answer (score 33):

As long as you don't use the shorthand iteration technique `for(Object a : Objects)` and use a traditional `for` loop, it works fine (you must traverse the list in reverse order as the example shows)

Try this:

```
for (Integer i = (companyinfos.size()-1) ; i>= 0 ; i--){
    String s = companyInfos[i];
    if(s.contains('a')){
        companyinfos.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that looping in reverse order is essential because otherwise, if you remove an item and the list gets shoter, you'll get an index out of bound exception if you try to fetch item past the end of the list.

Answer (score 7):

Salesforce prohitbits (or at least used to do that earlier) removing items from list while traversing it.

So, the solution would be to create another list, store all desired elements in there. For e.g.

```
List<CompanyInfo> companyinfos=new List<companyinfos>();
List<CompanyInfo> finalList=new List<companyinfos>();
companyinfos.add(***);
....

integer index=0;
For(CompanyInfo info: companyinfos)
{

    if(info.item!=****)
    {
        finalList.add(info);
    }
}  
companyinfos = finalList;
```

Answer (score 4):

**Using While loop to remove an element from a list while being looped**

If you want to remove an element in a list by checking for a specific condition, you can use `while` loop instead of `for` loop. By doing so, you could remove element from list using index.

Here is the sample code to do so

```
Integer i = 0;
while (i < companyinfos.size()){
    if(companyinfos.get(i).contains('a')){
        companyinfos.remove(i);
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: this does not work as the act of removing shifts the remaining elements to one lower array index value. For example, if all companies contain `a`, you'll retain the second, fourth, sixth, ... entries.

Comment: @cropredy This does work and its a tested code. Because even though the array index shifts, the index only increments when it doesn't find a match and if a match is found, it won't increment the index, hence it covers that scenario.

Comment: Hmmm.  When I did this, I had diff results.  I'll check my work again.  Sorry

Comment: No problem @cropredy :) Appreciate your suggestions and corrections on posts.

Answer (score 0):

First You should find the index of that letter from companyinfos list the remove that index
Try this and let me Know

```
for (Integer i = (companyinfos.size()-1) ; i>= 0 ; i--)
{
    if(companyinfos.contains('a')){
    Integer index =companyinfos.indexOf('a');
    companyinfos.remove(index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to remove using indexes. Just add needed the elements into another list.

```java
List<String> companyinfos = new List<String>();
List<String> newCompanyinfos = new List<String>();

companyinfos.add('a1');
companyinfos.add('a2');
companyinfos.add('a3');
companyinfos.add('b1');
companyinfos.add('b2');

for(String s:companyinfos){
    if(!s.contains('a')){
        newCompanyinfos.add(s); // you will get new list without As
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use delete/remove operation using short-hand iteration so there are many other ways by which you could achieve this.

So here is a forward approach that is *when you delete any element then the list get shortened so for this you don't need to increment the index*.

**Using for loop:**

```
List<String> companyInfos = new List<String>{'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2'};

for(Integer index = 0; index < companyInfos.size();)
    if(companyInfos[index].contains('a'))
         companyInfos.remove(index);
    else
        index++;

System.debug(companyInfos);
```

And you can also use using **While loop:**

```
List<String> companyInfos = new List<String>{'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2'};

Integer index = 0;
while(index < companyInfos.size())
    if(companyInfos[index].contains('a'))
        companyInfos.remove(index);
    else
        index++;

System.debug(companyInfos);
```

Comment: This answer doesn't appear to offer any new information.

Answer (score -2):

In Java it's agood practice to use the iterator when removing something from a list being looped:

```
List<String> companyinfos=new List<String>();
companyinfos.add('a1');
companyinfos.add('a2');
companyinfos.add('a3');
companyinfos.add('b1');
companyinfos.add('b2');

Iterator<String> it = companyinfos.iterator();

while(it.hasNext()){

String next = it.next();

if(next.contains('a')){
  it.remove();
}

}
```

Comment: Apex is not Java, although they share behaviors extensively. If this solution also applies to Apex, please [edit] to clarify that.